How to get the multiplicity of a certain root in a system of polynomial equation
Suppose I have a system of polynomial equations with base field $\mathbb{C}$ with $n$ equations and $n$ unknowns, how can I get the multiplicity of a certain solution? As an example, consider $$x^3=0\\y^4=0$$
I would expect the multiplicity of $(0,0)$ to be 12.
=============Edit============
The equation system has too much terms that not possible to get all roots and I'm interested in some specific ones. A better example explaining my question would be like $$x^3+x^4=0\\y^4=0$$
which has two roots $(0,0)$ and $(-1,0)$. With some priori knowledge I know that $(0,0)$ is a root and I would expect some algorithm could tell us it has multiplicity 12.

By "specific ones," do you mean they are known ahead of time?

@MichaelE2 Yes, I know those root satisfies other constraints and are easy to get.

What if you use Nasser's approach with an epsilon neighborhood around the root? (Abs[x - x0] < eps, Abs[y - y0] < eps for a small eps, maybe with WorkingPrecision -> 32) With a bounded domain, different methods may be used and they may be faster.

Maybe use the argument principle?


I would expect the multiplicity of (0,0) to be 12.

sol = SolveValues[{x^3 == 0, y^4 == 0}, {x, y}]
Tally[sol]


Regarding comment, this is what I get for the new input mentioned in V 14


Thanks for answer, the case is a bit more tricky. Solving the whole system of equation is not possible because it takes too long time. And I'm interested in multiplicities of certain roots. A better example would be $x^3+x^4=0,y^4=0$, which has two roots $(-1,0)$ and $(0,0)$. The latter would has multiplicity 12.

@PeterWu I am confused. When I typed sol = SolveValues[{x^3 + x^4 == 0, y^4 == 0}, {x, y}]; Tally[sol] I get what you asked for, which is {{{-1, 0}, 4}, {{0, 0}, 12}} I am using V 14. So I am not sure what is it you are asking for different than what Tally gives?  Could you post the actual specific example you want processed?  If Solve can't solve it, then ofcourse this solution will not work.

@Nasser I do not understand why, I get https://i.sstatic.net/lGDMeBx9.png

@minhthien_2016  I do not know. I am using V 14. May be you are using different version. I added screen shot on my answer also.

@Nasser I've added more details in question. There's no problem with your approach, it's just the equation system has too much terms that not possible to get all solutions, and I only need multiplicity of a certain root.

@PeterWu not possible to get all solutions even with NSolve instead of Solve ? As far as I know there is no method to find mutiplicity of a specific root from solvers. There is new option added in V 14 which is MaxRoots but this does not help of what you are asking for. May be someone else will have an idea.

@Nasser Possibly yes. It's a combinatorial-like problem. The number of roots goes exponentially and I guess the multiplicity should be linear. The first non-trivial case that I can't calculate by hand take me around an hour and still running. So I guess some commutative algebra approach could help me on that.
